# Is this possible to get_terms with meta data and image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to retrieve all the data of specific terms so i should not run the query again and again in the loop, to keep the page optimized.

So i would like to save all the data of the terms in the array.

Is it possible that i can extract **get_terms** with all their relative meta_data and image.

I tried the following but it wont give me the meta_data

```
$airlines_data = $terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => "air_line",
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields' => 'all',
    'meta_key' => 'IATA_airline_code',
]);
```

I am aware that there is custom SQL query, but i am seeking if there is a short wordpress hook for that?